# Can no longer connect to my phone's wifi hotspot Ubuntu v 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, android

At 3 o'clock Ubuntu was connecting to my phone as a wifi hotspot automatically.  At 4.30 after being left on suspend, it would not longer connect.

I have tried these:

1. Shut down and restart. No success.
2. Test the hotspot by booting to Windows 10.  Successful, so the hotspot is working.  I am using W10 to send this message.
3. Reenter the password. No success
4. change the password on my phone's hotspot configuration.  No success.

From the above it will be obvious that the the phone is being detected.  Its just that the password is not being accepted.

I do hope that someone can help.

Nick

Comment: Have you reboot your phone? Perhaps you should (regardless of other devices connecting fine).

Answer (score -1):

This is what worked on my Dell Inspiron Laptop.  I switched off wifi using the f2 key and then switched it on again.  That's all.

Nick